# What is wrong with the mysql query?

Tags: mysql

here is my code

```
SELECT * FROM bestbuy_product_details 
WHERE model_name like '%'+SELECT Keyword FROM segment+'%';
```

There are two tables, i want to check keyword from one table add like clause in model name in another table What is the syntax error i am not getting.

Comment: So, you DON'T get a syntax error, then? I don't understand... besides, `LIKE IN` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: The percent sign can not be arround the subselect

Comment: *"What is the syntax error i am not getting"* - You tell us.

Comment: Btw, you're using the wrong method to concatenate; you seem to come from a JS background. You also need to use either a subquery or a JOIN

Comment: I changed the query re4moved in from query now i am getting "#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row". The subselect returns more than on evalue how to check each value in model_name column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make join of both tables with join condition containing LIKE:

```
SELECT bpd.* FROM bestbuy_product_details bpd 
join segment s
ON bpd.model_name like '%'+s.Keyword+'%';
```

You cannot make LIKE from subquery - this is possible only with IN or EXISTS

Comment: Explain a bit more please, check [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it works for you i hope

```
 FROM bestbuy_product_details WHERE model_name like '%'+SELECT Keyword FROM segment+'%';`
```